# bash string explained as an variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string in a bash script

```
foo="~/mydir" (not foo=~/mydir)
```

then i need to create this directory using

```
mkdir ${foo}
```

is it any way the foo can be explained as

```
<"user's home directory">/mydir
```

but not

```
<"current work directory">/~/mydir.
```

Comment: You really should just set `foo` correctly. Use `foo=~/"mydir"` or `foo=$HOME/mydir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, you can use `$HOME` to indicate the user's home directory.

But beware:

> foo="~/mydir"

does not expand the tilde, so "echo $foo" still results in "~/mydir". If you want to expand the tilde, you can use

```
eval foo=$foo
```

Now "echo $foo" results for example in "/home/fred/mydir".
The tilde expansion is a little special, it is not a simple substitute for $HOME; look at the following:

```
foo="~/mydir"
echo ${foo/#\~/$HOME}       (reply: /home/administrator/mydir)
eval foo=$foo
echo $foo                   (reply: /home/administrator/mydir)
---
foo="~administrator/mydir"
echo ${foo/#\~/$HOME}       (reply: /home/administratoradministrator/mydir)
eval foo=$foo
echo $foo                   (reply: /home/administrator/mydir)
```

In other words: if you have always the simple form "~/...", substituting the tilde with $HOME works well. If you have the *more advanced* format, then eval is better, as you can see in the second example above.

The simple "eval foo=$foo" has problems with spaces in filenames:

```
foo="~administrator/mydir with spaces"
eval foo=$foo         (error: with: command not found)
```

The following syntax is better:

```
foo2=$(eval echo $foo)
echo $foo2            (ok: /home/administrator/mydir with space)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay using the tilde until when you need to create the directory :

```
foo="mydir"
....
mkdir ~/"$foo"
```

The tilde expands to the home directory only if unquoted.

> Relevant section of the Bash manual:
>   https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion